# Probability of a sequence of characters within a random sequence of characters

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, characters

I've been trying to work out a formula for the probability of a specified sequence of upper-case English characters of length $n$ appearing in a random sequence of upper-case English characters of length $X$ (which is $\ge n$).

I thought I had it with:

$$\frac{X-(n-1))}{26^n}$$

But that doesn't work for $n=1$.

If you can provide an answer, I'd very much appreciate you also showing (as far as you can) how you arrived at it, so I can try to understand what is, at the moment, beyond my own math.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how well the string can overlap with itself.    You can model this with a Markov chain, with states (Start) and the possible prefixes of your target string.  Thus for ABA the states are (Start), A, AB and ABA, and the transition matrix is 
$$ P = \pmatrix{25/26 & 1/26 & 0 & 0\cr
                24/26 & 1/26 & 1/26 & 0\cr
                25/26 &  0   & 0    & 1/26\cr
                  0   & 0    & 0    & 1\cr}$$
where e.g. the second row entries mean that in state A, if the next character is A you stay in state A, if it is B you go to state AB, and anything else returns you to (Start).
The probability you're looking for is the probability, starting in the (Start) state, of absorption by round $n$, which is 
$ ( P^n)_{1,4}$.

The characteristic polynomial is  $C(\lambda) = { { \left( \lambda-1 \right)  \left({\lambda}^{3}-
{\lambda}^{2}+26/17576\,\lambda-25/17576 \right) }}
$.  If the matrix is diagonalized as $S \Lambda S^{-1}$ where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\lambda_i$ (the roots of $C(\lambda)$), then $$(P^n)_{1,4} = \sum_{i=1}^4 S_{1,i} S_{i,4} \lambda_i^n$$.